# Image positioning////

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image as the background-image of a web page, I want  always to show the full height of the image and also it must be centered in the web page. The width of the image is bigger than its height. In this case I want the pic to be cut the same in both sides.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you demanded. Look at the CSS code for the body element.

```css
* { 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12193133/German-Shepherd-Puppy-Fetch.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```